# Reprojecting raster in QGIS gives nan

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I'm trying to reproject raster layers in QGIS. At the moment they are in `ESPG:4326` and I want to convert them to `ESPG:54009`. (Using `Save As...` and changing the CRS). However, this produces a layer of `nan` values.

Is there something obvious I am failing to do, to make it behave in this way?

Comment: Have you tried to reproject it (Raster -> projection -> transform (reproject))?

Comment: @Erik, wow this is embarrassing. I was trying to give the raster a non-standard file type `.tif.aux` Opps. Think I will delete this question

Comment: Leave it, it's a rather common mistake and the question might pop up again =) glad to help

Comment: I also learnt about the batch processing option available in the reproject, as well. Much faster than endless `Save As...`!

Comment: You should post your findings as an answer to your own question.